# Not able to mock out service in spring boot GraphQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, graphql, mocking

I'm using spring-boot-graphql and trying to mock out a service I have.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class UserData extends BaseData {

    ...

    public Mono<UserPage> getUsers(UserContext context, NameFilter filter, Pageable pageable) {
        var userTuple = filterByName(context, filter, pageable, User.class).as(trxOp::transactional);
        return userTuple.flatMap(listPageInfoTuple -> {
            return Mono.just(new UserPage(listPageInfoTuple.x(), listPageInfoTuple.y()));
        });
    }
}
```

In my test I am doing:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureHttpGraphQlTester
public class UserTests {

    @MockBean
    private UserData userData;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get users")
    public void testGetUsers() {
        var clientBuilder =
                WebTestClient.bindToServer()
                        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8091/graphql");

        HttpGraphQlTester graphQlTester = HttpGraphQlTester.builder(clientBuilder)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBasicAuth(username, password))
                .build();

        var usersToReturn = List.of(
                User.builder().name("Test User").build(),
                User.builder().name("Test User 2").build()
        );

        var userPageToReturn = Flux.fromIterable(usersToReturn).collectList()
                .flatMap(users -> {
                    var pageInfo = new PageInfo(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, true, true);
                    return Mono.just(new UserPage(users, pageInfo));
                });

        given(userData.getUsers(any(), any(), any())).willReturn(userPageToReturn);

        // top5users is a GraphQL request document.
        var userPage = graphQlTester.documentName("top5users").execute()
                .path("userPage")
                .entity(UserPage.class)
                .get();

        var users = userPage.users();

        assertThat(users).isNotNull();
        assertThat(users.size()).isEqualTo(2);
    }
}
```

I have 5 users in the DB already and users includes all the actual DB users, not the given response. So it seems that I am not mocking the data service out. Looking at spring-boot-graphql examples don't seem to have what I need, or I haven't looked hard enough. Bit lost!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the `assertThat()` methods are appropiate while testing with **Spring for GraphQL** in this manner. I would suggest you replaced these last lines:

```
graphQlTester.documentName("top5users").execute()
            .path("userPage")
            .entity(UserPage.class)
            .get();
```

....with something in the style of this (since I don't know your schema):

```
this.graphQlTester
            .documentName("artistas_test1")
            .execute()
            .path("artistas")
            .entityList(Artista.class)
            .hasSize(3);
```

This is my `artistas_test1.graphql`

```
query {
  artistas{
      apellido
  }
}
```

The idea is to evaluate in the graphQlTester itself.

Comment: The problem is that the execute function always reaches the actual data class. If I put a break point there, I hit it and userData is never mocked away. So, no matter what I assert or check, I am always comparing on database data, not given data.